# O que é uma classe lightweight?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, terminologia

Procuro uma explicação concisa para esta pergunta faz um tempo. O que encontrei foram textos confusos e pouco didáticos.

Comment: Poderia por uma ou mais referências para onde viu esse termo sendo usado?

Comment: Referência http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%28%27packages/pl2cpp.html%27%29  seção 2 Overview

Comment: Mostre os textos que explicam o termo. Quem sabe lendo eles eu possa produzir um texto melhor que você possa entender.

Comment: Este texto é uma tradução aproximada do link que deixei acima: "A área mais útil para explorar os recursos de C ++ é a conversão de tipo. Variáveis Prolog são dinamicamente tipificadas e toda a informação é passada em pelo uso do tipo term_t. Em C ++, term_t é incorporado na classe lightweight PlTerm. Construtores e definições de operador fornecem operações e integração flexíveis com tipos C importantes (char *, wchar_t *, longos e duplos)."

Comment: @Christopher Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu sei não há uma definição clara e universalmente aceita do que este termo significa.

Algumas pessoas poderão dizer que é uma [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) ([Plain Old Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure)) onde, grosso modo, os dados estão dispostos de forma compatível com o formato adotado pelo C.

Outras poderão dizer que são classes com um tamanho muito curto e que pode ser copiada mais facilmente em vez de ser passada como referência. OU ainda poderia ser uma que não tem uma tabela de virtualização, embora menos provável.

Em certos contextos pode haver uma explicação específica.